# How to add new <li> element each click?

Tags: javascript, html

First attempt at any sort of Javascript so be gentle aha

Have managed to have the page add the new list item to the inner html of an unordered list, but each time after that it just replaces the initial.

I feel like I'm missing something really basic here?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <script>
        function addItem() {
            var item = document.getElementById("task-field").value;
            document.getElementById("task-list").innerHTML = "<li> " + item + " </li>";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("task-list").innerHTML += "<li> " + item + " </li>";` Add the new list item with the old one by using `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```js
document.getElementById("task-list").innerHTML += "<li> " + item + " </li>";
```

instead of

```js
document.getElementById("task-list").innerHTML = "<li> " + item + " </li>";
```

The `+=` operator will use the current value of `innerHTML` and append your new content in this case. This as suggested by @Hassam Imam.

**Another way of doing it** is using `appendChild()` creating the new `<li>` item through JS. Like this:

```js
function addItem() {
    let item = document.getElementById("task-field").value;
    let parent = document.getElementById("task-list");
    
    // Create new node.
    let li_item = document.createElement("li");
    li_item.innerHTML = item;
    
    // Append child.
    parent.appendChild(li_item);
}
```

But this last method is probably too lengthy. The `+=` solution seems good. Just another way of doing it.

Comment: Yeah thats perfect, thanks heaps man!

.appendChild() might be a bit lengthy but probably much better practice for me to get into :+1:

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function addItem(item) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `${item}`;
    li.id = 'task-field';
    document.getElementById('task-list').appendChild(li);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.